# In C++ 20 how do I create a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` from specific not const values?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++20, c++-chrono

In C++ 20 how do I convert the following struct to a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`?

```
struct Time {
    //! Year
    unsigned int year;
    //! Month
    unsigned int month;
    //! Day
    unsigned int day;
    //! Hours
    unsigned int hours;
    //! Minutes
    unsigned int minutes;
    //! Seconds
    unsigned int seconds;
};
```

In other words how do I implement:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point convert(Time& time) {
    // ?
}
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use year/month/day to create a `year_month_day` object and convert it to `sys_days`, and then add the corresponding hours/minutes/seconds

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point convert(const Time& time) {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  return sys_days(
           year_month_day(year(time.year), month(time.month), day(time.day)))
       + hours(time.hours) + minutes(time.minutes) + seconds(time.seconds);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7qddj6ocx)

Comment: Thank you for your help! In your demo if I change the input to: `convert({2023, 2, 29, 12, 15, 00});` I get the output: `2023-03-01 12:15:00.00`. Is there some way I can check if a date is valid using `std::chrono`?

Comment: Note that this formulation assumes the input date/time is UTC.  chrono can handle the case it is a local input date/time with just a little bit more code.  The question wasn't clear on this point.

Comment: @Andy The `year_month_day` class has a member function `.ok()` which will yield `true` for valid dates and false for invalid dates.

Answer (score 0):

With info given by this struct you can fill `std::tm` structure, which can be converted to `time_t` via `mktime` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime

While `time_t` can be converted to `steady_clock::time_point` via `from_time_t`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t

Answer (score 0):

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point convert(const Time& time)
{
    tm convertTM;
    convertTM.tm_year = time.year - 1900;
    convertTM.tm_mon = time.month - 1; //months since January - [0, 11]
    convertTM.tm_mday = time.day;
    convertTM.tm_hour = time.hours;
    convertTM.tm_min = time.minutes;
    convertTM.tm_sec = time.seconds;
    return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(std::chrono::milliseconds(mktime(&convertTM) * 1000));
}
```